# Allocating More Than 4 GB Of Memory

Tags: vmware, memory, redhat-enterprise-linux

I am facing an issue with memory allocation.

I have:

Host OS: Microsoft Windows XP - Professional x64 Edition - Version 2003 - Service Pack 2.

Host Physical Memory: 8 GB

Guest OS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux WS release 4 (Nahant Update 5). I am not sure if it is 32 or 64 bits. The `lsb_release -a` command says that argument LSB Version: core-3.0-ia32, so I guess that would be 32 bits...

VMware Player Version: 2.5.2 build-156735

I would like that VMware Player could allocate more that 4 GB, but when I go to the setting, it only lists 4 GB. If I choose the "About" option, it actually says that I have 8 GB installed in the host machine.

This VMware image created by someone else and provided to me, apparently done with VMware Workstation 5.

Why can't I allocate 8 GB?

Where is the problem?

In the WMware Player Version, Guest OS or Host OS?

How can I solve this?

I understand that for this version of player there isn't one version for 32 and another for 64 bits.

Comment: Might want to re-edit the title to "Allocate more than 4Gb of memory to VMWare Guest"

Answer (score 5):

> The lsb_release -a command says that argument LSB Version: core-3.0-ia32, so I guess that would be 32 bits...

Try `uname -a` and look at the resulting output.  If you see `x86_64` then yes, it's 64-bit.

> I would like that VMware Player could allocate more that 4 GB, but when I go to the setting, it only lists 4 GB. If I choose the "About" option, it actually says that I have 8 GB installed in the host machine.
>
> This VMware image created by someone else and provided to me, apparently done with VMware Workstation 5.

Older images have limitations that are inherent to them, *based on what version they were made with*.  It could be as simple as the fact that the image was made in version 5; newer versions lift several limitations, and one of those might be the amount of memory supported.  For instance, I run 6.5 at work, which allows 2 CPUs.  Version 7 allows for 4.

---

Follow-up:

My Workstation 6.5 install reports that a version 5 image will have the following limitations:

- **3.5 GB memory limit**
- 2 processor limit
- 3 network adapter limit
- No USB 2.0
- No multiple monitor display
- No battery status
- No CPU hot plug
- No device hot plug
- No memory hot plug
- No LSI Logic SAS SCSI adapter
- No VMCI support

In other words, **you're not going to get it to run with 8 GB because it's a version 5 image**.  You'll want to consider migrating the machine to a newer format.

Answer (score 0):

The command `uname -a`  would show you your kernel info and help you determine if it's a 32-bit OS (x86) or 64-bit (x86_64).

As for your question regarding the allocation of more than 4 GB of memory...well, maybe someone can correct me if I'm wrong, but I do believe that VMWare would limit memory allocation based on your OS and if indeed your RHEL is 32-bit, then the 4 GB cap would make sense.

Comment: Don't see how VMWare could determine whether the guest is 32/64bit...

Comment: Maybe not VMWare as such but that particular product isn't supposed to be too feature-rich so it could easily be what's at fault.

Comment: VMware does know what the guest is.  It has to in order to provide the proper virtual bus etc...  If you look at the settings on a VM, you will see what vmware thinks it is.

Comment: Not only does VMware know if the guest is 32/64 bits, but it will (at least in 6.0/6.5) block a 32-bit host from running 64-bit guests.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try downloading the free 'VMWare Server', see how you get on with that, it should offer a lot more options.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* that VMware server (and Workstation and Fusion) only allow you to allocate up to 4 GB as a limitation of the tool. ESX certainly does not have the limitation, though.

Answer (score 0):

As per this post on vmware.com If found this solution here: http://communities.vmware.com/thread/332104

- First you need to determine if the VM is 64bit.
- Then you need to change the VMWare vmx file to support a higher virtual hardware version.

On the **Guest** use **uname -a** to determine if the Linux VMWare guestif 64bit.
E.g mine is 3.4.2-1.fc16.x86_64. The 64 at the end tells you it's 64bit.

On the **Host** edit the .vmx text file in a text editor:
 - Change virtualHW.version="8" (I suspect it's currently 5 as you said the VM was created with VMWS v5.